# How to always download the latest version of chromedriver and geckodriver?

Tags: linux, selenium, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops

Running automation tests on our CI. Currently, we are retrieving the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox as part of our setup, however, the versions of chromedriver and geckodriver we use are hardcoded because there seems to be no link to the latest version.

Ex. here is the line that downloads the latest firefox version

```
wget -nv -O ~/FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64"
```

While here is the line that downloads a specific version of geckodriver

```
wget -nv -O ~/geckodriver.tar.gz "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.1/geckodriver-v0.29.1-linux64.tar.gz"
```

Is there anyway to always get the latest chromedriver and geckodriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ddavison/936d843ad17140021fad) helps, at least for chromedriver:

```sh
version=$(curl http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
download_location= " http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ $version /chromedriver_linux64.zip "
rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
wget -P /tmp $download_location
unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d .
mv ./chromedriver ./chromedriver.linux
chmod u+x ./chromedriver.linux
```

Same idea for [geckodriver](https://gist.github.com/fercreek/a120f75dd30e3440822620dcff63b5c8):

```sh
install_dir= " /usr/local/bin "
json= $( curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest )
if [[ $( uname )  ==  " Darwin " ]] ;  then
url= $( echo " $json "  | jq -r ' .assets[].browser_download_url | select(contains("maces")) ' )
elif [[ $( uname )  ==  " Linux " ]] ;  then
url= $( echo " $json "  | jq -r ' .assets[].browser_download_url | select(contains("linux64")) ' )
else
 echo  " can't determine OS "
 exit 1
fi
curl -s -L " $url "  | tar -xz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver " $install_dir "
```

Comment: it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid two results (the .tar.gz and the .tar.gz.asc file):

```
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz.asc
```

I needed to add a new select clause at the end of the `jq` command.

Example:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | jq -r ' .assets[].browser_download_url | select(contains("linux64")) | select(endswith("tar.gz"))'
```

This selects only the needed URL (the .tar.gz archive URL) :

```
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz
```